# Python: clean the messy dataframe by its value

Tags: python, dataframe

I scraped a website and appended every page's data in a row to csv file. But data from different pages might not be the same, some data are missing since the webpage didn't provide its information.

CSV person:

```
C1    C2           C3         C4      C5      C6    C7
Annie Height: 145  Weight: 45 Car: no House:1 K-T-J X-Z
Jason Height: 189  Car:3 T Y
Ben   Height: 178  House:0 J-H X-Z
```

For example, I tried to clean 3 rows from my csv and wanted to set them in order.

What I expected:

```
Name       Height        Weight     Car      House    K   T   J  H  X  Y  Z
Annie   Height: 145   Weight: 45   Car:no   House:1   K   T   J     X     Z
Jason   Height: 189                Car:3                  T            Y    
Ben     Height: 178                         House:0           J  H  X     Z
```

If the values contains ":", I just need to place them in the right column. If the value contains "-", I need to split them to the right column. At the moment, I do it manually but it took such a long time, just wandering if it's possible to solve them in an efficient way.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to create a function that will treat line by line
:

- read the line and separate into a list through [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)
- Analyse each element using [RegEx](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search). For example, `^[^:]+:\s*` will help you to get whatever is before the ":".
- Store everything back in the right place (by using for example a [pandas Dataframe](https://pbpython.com/pandas-list-dict.html))